# Explanation Please

Tags: python, bioinformatics

This is my first every question here on this website. For a bit of background I am very interested in applying machine learning in preventative medicine as I believe this is what the future of medicine has in store. For this reason I have been teaching myself python via Rosalind.info. One question had us creating a function that can calculate the GC content of a sequence. One issue that I had was that when I used the first code, it evaluated to one. However, when I used the second code, it evaluated to the correct answer. If anyone can explain why this is the case that'd be much appreciated!

First try:

```
n = input("Paste in sequence here!").upper()

def cg_content(sequence):
    gc_count = 0
    total = len(sequence)
    for base in sequence:
        if base =='C' or 'G':
            gc_count += 1
        else:
            gc_count = gc_count
    percentage = float(gc_count)/float(total)
    print(percentage) 

cg_content(n)
```

Second Try:

```
n = input("Paste in sequence here!").upper()

def cg_content(sequence):
    gc_count = 0
    total = len(sequence)
    for base in sequence:
        if base =='C' or base == 'G':
            gc_count += 1
        else:
            gc_count = gc_count
    percentage = float(gc_count)/float(total)
    print(percentage) 

cg_content(n)
```

I know it has something to do with the 'or' statement but I thought that both statements are essentially equivalent regardless of whether the '==' was there once or twice.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get different outputs resides in:

```
if base =='C' or 'G':
```

which differs from:

```
if base =='C' or base == 'G':
```

In the first case, you are evaluating the truth value of the expression `'G'` which is a variable of type `char`. Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) says that:

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method
>   that returns zero, when called with the object.

Therefore, `if 'G'` evaluates always to true.

---

**Funny story**:

Even though `'G'` evaluates as `True`, the following expression evaluates as`False`:

```
if 'G' == True:
    print("I will be never printed")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not equivalent.  The first code is basically:

`if (base == 'C') or ('G'):`

or in other words, `if base == 'C'` is true, or `if 'G'` is true.  Clearly `if 'G'` makes no sense.  In general, 0 = false, and non-zero = true, so `if 'G'` will likely always be true.

Therefore, you're saying `if base == 'C' or True` and that will always be true, so the first if clause always wins.  Anything `or True` is `True`...even `if False or True` ;)

Answer (score 0):

In python any non-empty string is interpreted as True (affirmative)

thus `base == 'C' or 'G'` which is same as `(base =='C')  or 'G'` is always interpreted as True, regardless of what is value of `base`.

While Python is often intuitive and elegant it follow some strict set of rules rather than common sense in interpreting code. The tradition of interpreting non-null/non-empty values as True value stems from C with which standard Python interpreter tightly inter-operates. It is not very strict or intuitive but often allows for simpler and elegant code.